# Problem with missing JSON functions on PHP 5.2.6 / Plesk 8.4

Tags: php, linux, apache2, plesk

I have a vserver running openSuse 10.3, Apache 2 and Plesk 8.4. I can update/upgrade neither, as it is apparently not recommended to upgrade openSuse 10.3 (and an update to the EOL 10.4 does not seem to make much sense) and Plesk fails to update no matter what version I try (even fails to upgrade to 8.4.1). Still I can live with that somehow, primarily because I don’t have the time to do a fresh remote install on the vserver.

What really is a problem is, that though the installed PHP is 5.2.6 it has no zip library and no json functions. The first is probably because PHP was not compiled with --enable-zip. The second is a big mystery though. As I understand it, it always comes with PHP unless its compiled with the --disable-json configure option. This is however not the case. And the json extension module is just not there. I even tried to enable it with extension=json.so with no luck either.

the configure options of my PHP are (as shipped with Plesk 8.4)

```
'../configure' 
'--prefix=/usr' 
'--datadir=/usr/share/php5' 
'--mandir=/usr/share/man' 
'--bindir=/usr/bin' 
'--with-libdir=lib' 
'--includedir=/usr/include' 
'--sysconfdir=/etc/php5/apache2' 
'--with-config-file-path=/etc/php5/apache2' 
'--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/conf.d' 
'--enable-libxml' 
'--enable-session' 
'--with-mm' 
'--with-pcre-regex=/usr' 
'--enable-xml' 
'--enable-simplexml' 
'--enable-spl' 
'--enable-filter' 
'--disable-debug' 
'--enable-inline-optimization' 
'--disable-rpath' 
'--disable-static' 
'--enable-shared' 
'--program-suffix=5' 
'--with-pic' 
'--with-gnu-ld' 
'--with-system-tzdata=/usr/share/zoneinfo' 
'--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs2' 
'--disable-all' 
'--disable-cli'
```

As I understand it, PECL is not an option with 5.2.6. Or am I mistaken? Even if I was not, the openSuse repository only goes as far as PHP 5.2.4. The openSuse install even came without zypper, which I had to manually install.

So is there a way to get ziplib and json running in PHP 5.2.6 without having to recompile the binary?

Comment: "PECL is not an option with 5.2.6" - what makes you think this?

Comment: I might have read this on other boards. And I did not find any PECL (I think it’s the php-pear package in yast for 5.2.6). but as I already said, it’s a big possibility, that I am mistaken.

Comment: I just checked http://php.net/releases and did only find PECL 5.2.6 packages for Windows.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to SO

Comment: This should be moved to Unix&Linux instead.

Comment: While there are various silly hacks to solve the problem, the right solution is to MAN UP and upgrade your software which was EOL years ago. You are not just putting your site and your users at risk but leaving a loaded weapon lying around for anyone to use.

Answer (score 1):

If this has happened it sounds like for some reason the json extension was not included for some reason. This can be fixed by downloading the `json.so` file from the PHP source repository, uploading it to the `/usr/lib/php5/extensions` directory and then restarting Apache. Will work fine from there.